# Difference between None and <no value>

Tags: python, numpy

I'm familiar with Java's `null` and C++'s `nullptr`, plus similar concepts from several scripting languages. `None` looks remarkably like Python's version of that same old theme.

And then I ran across this function declaration:

```
 numpy.amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>, initial=<no value>, where=<no value>)
```

What's the difference between `None` and `<no value>`? I'm guessing this is just a documentation generation thing when there's no defined default, but then why not just not list a default at all?

Comment: You can check [the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d9b1e32cb8ef90d6b4a47853241db2a28146a57d/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2629-L2746) and you'll see that they created their own `_NoValue` object (most likely via `_NoValue = object()`). They need to do this because any value would be sensible, including `None`, so a separate object is required to indicate that the user didn't provide a value (since that can't be distinguished in the function). So indeed, the `<no value>` is a special representation for documentation purposes.

Comment: @a_guest: it's [a custom class](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c31cc36a8a814ed4844a2a553454185601914a5a/numpy/_globals.py#L57-L79) that behaves just a lot like `None` does, with a helpful `repr()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a documentation thing, there is no such concept *in Python itself*.

Take into account that `None` in itself is *also a valid object*. Sometimes you want to accept `None` as a valid value for an argument, so you can't use that as the default value for an optional parameter. You wouldn't be able to distinguish between the default `None` and someone passing in `None` explicitly, since it's a singleton!

If I needed to define such a function, I'd use a *different* singleton sentinel. You can create one from just about anything, but simplest is to use an `object()` instance:

```
_sentinel = object()

def foo(bar, baz=_sentinel):
    if baz is not _sentinel:
        # baz has a defined value, because it is
        # not a reference to the sentinel
```

And perhaps I'd also use `<no value>` in the documentation to indicate that `baz` is optional. It all depends on the local conventions. The Python documentation itself uses `[...]` around optional arguments, for example.

`numpy.amin()` is actually a proxy function; it delegates the actual work either to [`numpy.minimum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) (via [`ufunc.reduce()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce), or, *if the first argument is a subclass that implements an `amin()` method*, to that method of the subclass. Because the latter should be able to set their own defaults, using a sentinel lets the `numpy.amin()` implementation pass on only those keyword arguments that actually were given an explicit value, without dictating what kind of sentinel the subclass `.amin()` implementations should use or what types they accept.

The Numpy project actually [created their own singleton class to act as a sentinel](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c31cc36a8a814ed4844a2a553454185601914a5a/numpy/_globals.py#L57-L79) so they could give the object a helpful `repr()` output:

```
>>> from numpy._globals import _NoValue
>>> _NoValue
<no value>
>>> type(_NoValue)
<class 'numpy._globals._NoValueType'>
```

Finally, `None` should **not** be compared with `null` or `nullptr`. `None` is a singleton object, something to reference instead of another object. `null` and `nullptr` are used to signal the *absence* of a reference, and can be passed around like other scalar values. You can't do this in Python, where everything is a valid reference to an object. (At most, you get a `NameError` or `UnboundLocal` exception if you tried to use a name that hasn't been bound to yet in its namespace).

Comment: "You can't create empty references in Python." - well, you kind of can. Locals are empty references before you assign something to them, or if you `del` their value. You can't pass around and manipulate an empty reference in Python like you could with `null` or `nullptr`, though.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: You can't pass those around. You'd get a `UnboundLocal` exception instead.

Comment: So what's the functional difference here?  In general, what does it mean when I set a param to `None` that would have defaulted to `numpy._NoValue`?

Comment: @MarkStorer: That's entirely dependent on the implementation of whatever thing used `numpy._globals._NoValue`, on what meaning that function or object attaches to `None`.

Comment: @MarkStorer: e.g. for `numpy.amin()`, the value of `keepdims` is passed on to `a.amin()`, but only if not left to the default. Because `a` can be any arbitrary subclass of `numpy.ndarray`, it is dependent on the exact array type you pass in if `None` has any specific meaning. The developers just didn't want to limit what kinds of values can be used, or prevent those types picking a different default.

Comment: If `null` signals the *absence* of a reference, then why is it called "null *reference*"? That sounds like it *is* a reference. I don't understand the difference you're describing. What exactly is the thing you can't do in Python? I.e., what does the Java code look like?

Comment: @HeapOverflow: that's way too broad to answer in comments. See the [Wikipedia article on null pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer), there is no one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: That article doesn't say it signals the absence of a reference. It says it indicates that *the reference* does not refer to a valid object. It also mentions `None` as Python's version of a null pointer (or null value).

Comment: @HeapOverflow: it's a common *simplification*.

Comment: Mark, In `amin` (and possibly other `ufunc`) `keepdims` can be `True`, `False` or an integer (which will be True if not 0).  `_NoValue` is treated as `False`.  You can test that behavior yourself.  It cannot be `None` (again see for yourself).  `initial` has its own expectations.

Comment: @hpaulj: `_NoValue` is actually truthy when tested as a bool. Code using `_NoValue` [*explicitly tests fro it*](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L75). `keepdims` is set to `_NoValue` because any other `keepdims` value is passed on to the array if it has been subclassed, and no assumptions are made about possible value types or if something changed the default. `np.minimum.reduce()` is otherwise called and [`ufunc.reduce()` sets `keepdims=False`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce).

Answer (score 2):

The code for the `np._NoValue` class:

```
class _NoValueType(object):
    """Special keyword value.

    The instance of this class may be used as the default value assigned to a
    deprecated keyword in order to check if it has been given a user defined
    value.
    """
    __instance = None
    def __new__(cls):
        # ensure that only one instance exists
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance = super(_NoValueType, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.__instance

    # needed for python 2 to preserve identity through a pickle
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, ())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<no value>"
File:           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/_globals.py
Type:           type
```